# Xamarin app crashes when using VB.Net Now() or Today()

Tags: android, vb.net, xamarin

I have an object Shift with a property DateAndTime as Date.
When I try to set this property using Now() the VS debugger pops up an error

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 0100006b from typeref (expected class 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')'

If I hard code a date e.g. #2022-12-25 3:10 PM# all is fine. What does Xamarin expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using those in any VB code, never mind a Xamarin app. Don't use VB Runtime functions (methods from modules in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace) when there are equivalent or better options that are not VB-specific. In this case, use the `Date.Now` and `Date.Today` properties, exactly as any C# developer would.

Note that `Date` is a VB data type that maps to the .NET `DateTime` structure. You can use either in your code but, if you use `Integer` rather than `Int32` then you should be using `Date` rather than `DateTime` too.

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew a lot of VB functions map to a .net function but it's hard to know (maybe Microsoft could have a link to the proper .net one?). In any case, using Date.Now fixed the problem, cheers.